# How to use Rails 3 scope to filter on habtm join table where the associated records don't exist?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, join, where-clause

I have an `Author` model which habtm :feeds.  Using Rails 3 want to setup a scope that finds all authors that have no associated feeds.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :feeds
    scope :without_feed, joins(:feeds).where("authors_feeds.feed_id is null")

end
```

...doesn't seem to work. It feels like a simple thing.  What am I missing here?

Comment: It feels like the joins(:feeds) is performing an inner join which will only select an author if they have feeds in the first place?

Comment: It is indeed doing an inner join: `SELECT authors.* FROM authors INNER JOIN authors_feeds ON authors_feeds.author_id = authors.id INNER JOIN feeds ON feeds.id = authors_feeds.feed_id WHERE (authors_feeds.feed_id is null)` and what I want is an outer join. Any help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To my knowledge ActiveRecord/Arel do not have a means of defining outer joins. So you'll have to write a bit more SQL than normal. Something like this should do the trick:

```
    scope :without_feed, joins('left outer join authors_feeds on authors.id=authors_feeds.author_id').where('authors_feeds.feed_id is null')
```

I am of course guessing at your table names and foreign keys. But that should give you the picture.

Comment: To do the inverse of this (return only Authors that do have X) but with a simple Author has_many Addresses, this crazy thing (pieced together from this post and [this blog comment](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1093-Getting-One-Record-Per-Group-From-A-One-to-Many-Join.htm#comments)) seems to work: `scope :with_address, joins("left outer join (select author_id from addresses group by author_id) as addresses on addresses.author_id = authors.id").where("addresses.author_id is not null")`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails >= 5, you can do it like this:

```ruby
scope :without_feed, -> {
  left_outer_joins(:feeds)
  .where(authors_feeds: { author_id: nil })
}

scope :with_feed, -> {
  left_outer_joins(:feeds)
  .where.not(authors_feeds: { author_id: nil })
}
```

Comment: Yep, using Arel is the better way. Glad Rails 5+ lets us do this.